# Extract operator $, really needed?

Tags: r

Studying http://data.princeton.edu/R/linearModels.html, I see

```
> lmfit = lm( change ~ setting + effort )
```

To use `change`, `setting` and `effort` from previously loaded data (`> fpe <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/effort.dat")`).

Executing the above command without `$` I get

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'change' not found
```

If I do it using `$` like

```
> lmfit = lm( fte$change ~ fte$setting + fte$effort )
```

Then it works.

So, why they present it this way `> lmfit = lm( change ~ setting + effort )`?

Comment: It looks like they `attach` the data prior to this command being made. When that is done, you don't need the `$`. However, I think it is generally considered poor practice to `attach` data. A better solution might be `lmfit <- lm(change ~ setting + effort, data = fte)`

Comment: It actually says *so make sure the fpe data frame is attached to your current session* just prior to that code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the dataframe:

```
lmfit = lm( change ~ setting + effort, data=fte)
```